# How do I automate deployment to Docker with CircleCI?

Tags: docker, automation, circleci

My circle.yml file and my CircleCI account are set up to use Docker for testing already, but I'd like to move to continuous deployment upon a successful build.

Here's what I have so far in circle.yml:

```
machine:
  services:
    - docker

dependencies:
  override:
    - docker info
    - docker build -t pgeiss/appname .

test:
  override:
    - docker run -d -p 8080:8080 pgeiss/appname; sleep 10
    - curl --retry 10 --retry-delay 5 -v http://localhost:8080/res.json
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A few things need to happen for this to work properly. First, add a `deployment` section to circle.yml:

```
deployment:
  main: # or whatever your deployment is called
    branch: master # or whatever branch you want to deploy
    commands:
      - docker login -e (your email here) -u (your username here) -p (your password here)
      - docker push pgeiss/appname
      - ./start.sh
```

*Thanks to [this blog post](http://www.mikeheijmans.com/docker/2015/09/07/automated-docker-deployment-with-circle/) for the following script.* Then, make a file called start.sh in the top level of your repository (if you use a different name, change the circle.yml's last line) that contains the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

echo "stopping running application"
ssh $DEPLOY_USER@$DEPLOY_HOST 'docker stop dodsv'
ssh $DEPLOY_USER@$DEPLOY_HOST 'docker rm dodsv'

echo "pulling latest version of the code"
ssh $DEPLOY_USER@$DEPLOY_HOST 'docker pull pgeiss/appname-webapp:latest'

echo "starting the new version"
ssh $DEPLOY_USER@$DEPLOY_HOST 'docker run -d --restart=always --name dodsv -p 80:5432 pgeiss/appname:latest'

echo "success!"

exit 0
```

Finally, to allow the script to work you'll need to set the script to be executable with `chmod` and add the environment variables and your `DEPLOY_USER`'s ssh key (preferably) or credentials (if no ssh key) to CircleCI. After doing that CircleCI should deploy your app after a successful build.